# Can hadoop file system( HDFS ) store video type file?

Tags: image, video, hadoop, hdfs

as title, I want to know can hadoop file system store video or image file directly?
Or I have to do something first so that I could store video or image file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video and Image files can be stored in HDFS.

If you want to process video and image files, you need to figure out how to split this files and write your own InputFormat and OutputFormat and a RecordReader. You can search the net for how to create these classes.

Comment: I have been seeing `If you want to process video and image files` and similar response in many questions regarding storing images and videos on HDFS. What kind of processing is this referring to. Is it like creating thumbnails, resizing and cropping or what?

Comment: Processing video can be understand as transcoding, changing the codec and format, resizing, applying filter, cropping or simply you are doing something with the video.

Answer (score 0):

It's a filesystem, you can put files on it. It doesn't matter what they are.

Comment: so it also can process in hadoop map/reduce?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hadoop SequenceFile for this, it provides storage for binary k-v pairs and can be used directly as hadoop's input